# How to get current component name in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to hide a header and a footer in Angular2 when a user hits a promo page.

```
https://example.com/promo
```

My app compontent is as follows:

```
  <login-bar></login-bar>
  <banner *ngIf="showComponent()"></banner>
  <navbar *ngIf="showComponent()"></navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer *ngIf="showComponent()"></footer>
```

If the user is on the page: /promo I want to hide the banner, navbar and footer component.

In my code I have this:

```
export class AppComponent {   constructor(
      private router:Router

  ) {}

  showComponent(): Boolean {
    ****
    How do I check the current route?
    ****
    var currentRoute = ** enter magic here **
    return (currentRoute === "promo") ? true : false;   
  } 
}
```

So my question, what is the best way to find the current page/route I am on so that I can show or hide the components?

Comment: Try activatedroute or  router to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently activated route, you can inject the `ActivatedRoute` service. This will give you access to, among other things, an Observable of the current route's URL.

```
export class AppComponent {

  // Bind to this:
  isPromo = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      route.url.subscribe(segments => {
          this.isPromo = segments[0].path === "promo";
      });
  }

}
```